# In Bamboo Build server how do I prevent 2 particular plans from running at the same time?

Tags: bamboo

I am running Bamboo 3.4.2. I have 2 plans (among many), one scheduled and one commit triggered, that I need to prevent running at the same time as they conflict.  They are in the same Project so if there is a way to only allow one Plan in a Project to run that would be entirely acceptable.  I am entirely willing to commit an agent to just service that Project but I can't find a way of doing that.

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one pretty easy way to do this.

On the 2 plans in question, set a requirement for a particular capability, such as "MachineName" equals "Bob".

Then set up the single agent you would like to run those plans and give it a capability such that it matches, like "MachineName" equals "Bob".

Obviously, "Bob" may not be the ideal choice there.

Comment: Worked great, thanks.  It does seem like they could have created a more straight forward way of doing it that wouldn't require creating an affinity to a particular agent, like a "don't run when these jobs are running" property.